# Calculate the total counts using pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like this:

```
student     class       subject       date          status

jack        class-1     maths       20150101        fail
jack        class-1     maths       20150205        win
jack        class-1     maths       20150310        fail
jack        class-1     maths       20150415        fail
mathew      class-2     maths       20150102        win
mathew      class-2     maths       20150208        win
mathew      class-2     maths       20150315        win
john        class-3     maths       20150125        fail
```

it is the status of maths competion of students in different dates,
Some students not miss the competetion on certain dates.
How I can get the results like this using pandas `pivot table` function

```
student     class       subject  fail   win
jack        class-1     maths      3     1
mathew      class-2     maths      0     3
john        class-3     maths      1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['student','class','subject'], 
                    columns='status', 
                    values='date', 
                    aggfunc=len,
                    fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
status student    class subject  fail  win
0         jack  class-1   maths     3    1
1         john  class-3   maths     1    0
2       mathew  class-2   maths     0    3
```

Last you can remove columns name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
#pandas bellow 0.18.0
#df.columns.name = None
print (df)
  student    class subject  fail  win
0    jack  class-1   maths     3    1
1    john  class-3   maths     1    0
2  mathew  class-2   maths     0    3
```